# Difference between 'directorate' and 'department'

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

What is the difference between 'directorate' and 'department'?

Is a department, like, a ministry and directorate a sub-ministry? In the political/business context, a directorate doesn't exist on its own and is always subordinate to a department (which is, in turn, a specialized division of a government or company itself), is that right?

Comment: As a best practice, you should put your main question in the question itself, not as the title of the question. This is explained at [this meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/4797#4797). When a question starts with a follow-on, like [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/3f424ee1-3de7-4c88-886d-ba836d15ef7c/view-source), or like [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/876a9d3f-01f6-4031-8eda-d7962eaac69c/view-source), or like [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/9ce25f52-845a-43d7-b30a-74f2e013366b/view-source), it can be a bit confusing.

Comment: How can those questions be confusing? If they are in titles, on the contrary, they are easier to notice. Why can't bodies be follow-ons to titles? What's wrong with it? You've already read the title when you clicked the question. Why should I repeat it in the body?

Comment: Those are your original questions, before they were edited, taken from the revision history. I think they do a good job of showing what a question looks like when you put the main question in the title and follow that on in the body of a question. Anyway, I was just trying to give some helpful advice from a seasoned veteran. Ignore it if you want – I'm not going to waste any more time arguing about it.

Comment: For further reading: see Section 4.3 of [this comprehensive meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2631).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may differ between organisations, but a "directorate" is normally everything that is under one particular *director* of the company. "Departments" are usually then smaller areas within the directorate, normally under a *department head* or *department manager*.

Organisations differ in structure, and I would say that this applies when an organisation has more than one director with different areas of responsibility - otherwise there would be no need to divide the organisation into directorates, as everything would fall under the director or a board of directors.

Comment: Lexico says otherwise, 'A section of a government department in charge of a particular activity' (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/directorate).

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev If you have a dictionary definition, why are you asking the question? I've based my answer on my experience working in a UK government organisation.

Comment: Don't flip out, I just asked (without actually asking but still) your opinion on that

Comment: @I'm not "flipping out". My thoughts are that the word "section" is not business-specific and says nothing about the nature of what goes on within that division of a company. Arguably, a directorate is a section of a company, as is a department. I don't believe a company would use the word "director" if they didn't have management at "director" level, but every organisation is able to design a heirarchy the way they want to.